# Problemas no relacionamento de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, constraint

Conseguem me ajudar nessa ?

Sendo objetivo nem pai nem filhos permitem a exclusão, é um laço familiar forte que foi criado aqui:

mysql> delete from routes where id = 1;

ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sgd_panificadora`.`os`, CONSTRAINT `os_routes_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`routes_id`) REFERENCES `routes` (`id`))

mysql> delete from drivers where id = 6;

ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sgd_panificadora`.`os`, CONSTRAINT `os_routes_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`routes_id`) REFERENCES `routes` (`id`))

Se alguém entender o motivo pelo qual não consigo excluir "drivers" nem "routes", pq cheguei ao extremo haha.

Vou fazer essa exclusão agora de outra forma, mas aguardo melhor entendimento sobre a situação.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id | int unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(191) | NO | | NULL | |
| email | varchar(191) | NO | UNI | NULL | |
| password | varchar(191) | NO | | NULL | |
| cpf | varchar(191) | YES | | NULL | |
| deleted_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
| created_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id | int unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| name | varchar(191) | NO | | NULL | |
| drivers_id | int unsigned | NO | MUL | NULL | |
| created_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES | | NULL | |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Referente ao "show create table" teremos isso:

```
| drivers | CREATE TABLE `drivers` (
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`cpf` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `drivers_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |



| routes | CREATE TABLE `routes` (
`id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`drivers_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `routes_drivers_id_foreign` (`drivers_id`),
CONSTRAINT `routes_drivers_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`drivers_id`) REFERENCES `drivers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite Christian, ao que me parece o problema é que existe um terceira tabela (ao que parece seu nome é 'os') que possui uma coluna id_routes, a qual é uma chave estrangeira vinda da tabela routes (e, possivelmente, essa chave não usa o cascade).
Dessa forma, provavelmente existem registros da rota 1 nessa terceira tabela, que impedem de deletar diretamente uma rota.
Nesse caso, você precisaria primeiro excluir os registros da tabela 'os', para depois excluir de dentro da tabela routes.
Ou opcionalmente, você pode dropar a chave estrangeira da tabela 'os' e criar uma nova com cascade.